# How do I prefix my log messages with the current date and time?

Tags: python, django, logging, python-3.9, django-3.0

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2. I have logging configured in my settings.py file

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

When I do logging in one of my classes, I do it like so

```
import logging
...
class TransactionService:
    def __init__(self):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


    def my_method(self, arg1, arg2):
            ...
        self._logger.info("Doing some logging here.")
```

How do I configure my logger such that when the message is printed out, it is prefixed by the current date and time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me (adapted from thorndeux's answer):

```
import logging.config

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'prepend_date': {
            'format': '{asctime} {levelname}: {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'prepend_date',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logging.info('foo')
logging.warning('bar')
```

prints

```
2021-11-28 16:05:13,469 INFO: foo
2021-11-28 16:05:13,469 WARNING: bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a formatter to your logger. For example:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'prepend_date': {
            'format': '{asctime} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'prepend_date',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

Comment: Gave this a whirl but the date still doesn't appear.

Comment: There is a typo in prepend_datA. Did you copy that by any chance?

Comment: I cut and pasted just now what you have in your answer, but i don't see any dates being prepended to my log file lines.

Comment: Yes, but I have a typo in my answer: I called the formatter 'prepend_date', but when I assign it to the handler I mistyped 'prepend_data' with an 'A' at the end. So, if you change that it should work.

Edit: I will change the typo, once you see where it is...

Comment: Please **edit** your answer now instead of trying to describe the typo; OP can always check the edit history to see what has been changed.

Comment: Also, `prepend_date` doesn't prepend the date. It has the `levelname` before the date - prepend means add at the front.

Comment: @desertnaut Done. Didn't know about the edit history.

Comment: @VinaySajip Nitpicky, but fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), please read the full article.

```
import logging

FORMAT = '%(asctime)s  %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info("Doing some logging here.")
```

This would print:

```
2021-11-29 14:06:59,825  Doing some logging here.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is missing in your example is `formatters` (add to LOGGING dict following):

```py
LOGGING = {
    ...
    "formatters": {"console": {"format": "%(asctime)s %(message)s"}},
    # and add it to handlers
    "handlers": {"console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "console"}},
    ...
}
```

Another thing that you may want to change logging setup in classes to something like

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
class TransactionService:

    def my_method(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...
        logger.info("Doing some logging here.")
```

You can also find full example in [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#examples) (last of examples in that subsection):

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'project.logging.SpecialFilter',
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'myproject.custom': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    }
}
```